# Am I allowed to swim in the Austrian Alps lakes?

Tags: legality, austria, alps

The title really says it all, is it legal to swim in the lakes in the Austrian Alps?

Answer (score 8):

It is allowed if there's no sign declaring it as `Naturschutzgebiet/Naturschutzzone` this is german for `natural reserve` if there's no such sign or you know for sure your not in such a reserve, it's safe to swim legally. However, best practice is to ask at the local tourist information center.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a copy paste from wikipedia:*

> The right to roam in Austria, particularly in forests and mountainous
>   areas, is called Wegefreiheit. Since 1975 the right to roam in forests
>   is guaranteed by Federal law. In particular, walking, running, hiking,
>   and resting are automatically allowed to the public in most forest
>   areas. However, horse riding, bike riding, and camping are not, and
>   may only be practised with the land owner's permission. A large
>   proportion of the forest area in Austria is owned by government bodies
>   such as the Österreichische Bundesforste, but the same restrictions
>   still apply. In some circumstances forests may be closed to the public
>   for environmental reasons. The situation in mountainous areas is less
>   clear, and differs from state to state. Some states, such as
>   Carinthia, Styria, and Salzburg guarantee a right to roam in
>   mountainous areas (usually defined as above the tree line), for all
>   recreational activities. In other states, such as Tyrol, Lower
>   Austria, and Burgenland, no explicit right to roam exists and land
>   owners reserve the right to deny access. In practice, however, such
>   restrictions are rarely enforced, since mountain tourism is an
>   important industry in Austria

**Sources** : Wikipedia ([article Freedom to roam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_to_roam))

Comment: I'm not sure whether that answers the question, unless it's to say "I don't know!" - are are you suggesting that the exclusion of swimming from the third sentence is a "No"?